# Concatenate a Dictionary to a string of "key=val&key=val..."

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I pass a querystring to a page in my Windows Phone app : `page.xaml?key=val&key2=val`.

I received it as `NavigationContext.QueryString`, and would like to pass it to a Web Service : `http://ws.site.com/key=val&key2=val`

Since `NavigationContext.QueryString` is a `Dictionary<string, string>` is there a simple way to concatenate it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure:

```
var entries = NavigationContext.QueryString.Select
      (x => Uri.EscapeDataString(x.Key) + "=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(x.Value));

string joined = string.Join("&", entries.ToArray());
```

(In .NET 4 you could avoid converting to an array, but alas not on WP7.)